# How to use OcaIDE debugger in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ocaml

I am a bit new to this. I am not able to figure out that how to use the debugger? I am not able to view help contents either in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check [here](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/forum/index.php?sid=e14457dd091d3efdce0dfdd5ec2384e0) or try to contact authors directly.